# Clicking on search button to search through sqlite database according to user input and display results in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, search, android-arrayadapter

What code must I add to make the search button function?

Clicking on search button to search through **SQLite database** according to user input and display results in `ListView`.

**PostLogin.java** (search)

```
 Button btnSend;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.post_login);
  btnSend=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.search);
      DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
      db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));        
      db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas", "9199999999"));
      db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "9522222222"));
      db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "9533333333"));

  btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @override
    public void onClick(View v) {

 EditText userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);


 Intent intent = new Intent(PostLogin.this, Result.class);
     startActivity(intent);  

  });
 }
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone


    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}




// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

**post_login.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/edit_text"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

 <View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dip"
android:background="#000000" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:minHeight="64dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**result.xml** (ListView)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/result"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

 <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#000000" />

     <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">
     </ListView>
```

Comment: Just a question , Why are you calling activity  on Click of a button ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on android. As mention in my post, I want to click on the search button to search through the database according to the user's input and display the results in result.xml which uses ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to Achieve this :

1. Create an ListAdapter to render the list items
2. Set the ListAdapter to the listView. Using listView.setAdapter();
3. Query to the database on Click - which you are already doing.
4. Iterate resultset and put in ArrayList - In your case its just a string then ArrayList
5. At last call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

You can look for default adapter as well. 
Reference : http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add function to get details from DB based on the user input. (eg:) if you want to get the list of users with a name starting with the letter "J",

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE FirstName LIKE 'J%';
```